# Highlight search keywords of 'org-search-view' in org-agenda

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When I do 'org-search-view' (C-c a s) in org-agenda and visit the file by pressing SPC (org-agenda-show-and-scroll-up) on the result in agenda buffer, I want to highlight the search keywords on the original file.

Can I do that?

I'm using Emacs 22 on OS X Snow Leopard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should file an Org-mode enhancement request, using `M-x report-emacs-bug`. (Yes, that is for enhancement requests as well as bug reports.)